# How can I create dynamic options based on the existing bundles from hook_drush_command()?

Tags: 7, drush

I want to create dynamic options based on the entity types (returned by `entity_get_info()` function) inside the `hook_drush_command()`. There's no bootstrapped Drupal available at all, so the `db_query()` `entity_get_info()` functions aren't available. How can `hook_drush_command()` get site information?

(The module is inside the ~/.drush/mymodule directory.)

Comment: You can't (neither can Drush itself). You need to execute Drush under an active site, then you'll be able to use Drupal's API

Comment: The problem is, even if I execute the help command when I'm under an active site, I can't access to the site db inside the `hook_drush_command()` function.

Comment: That makes sense - that hook is for registering Drush commands, so it needs to be able to work whether there's an active site or not. Basically you can't do it the way you want to, it wouldn't conceptually work. The callback/parameters for the custom command will have to provide the functionality

Comment: Ok, than how can I say to the user, what the user can use, when it variate from site to site, what entities are defined?

Comment: And it's also interesting, because until it was a Drupal module, it worked and it was accessible the `entity_get_info()` function from `hook_drush_command()`...

Comment: However it was happening, you must have been executing it in the context of a boostrapped Drupal site, there's no other way Drush would have been able to find the files containing those functions (Drush doesn't have a copy of Drupal inside it, it uses the one in the folder it's currently operating on directly). I haven't needed to write a command that takes user input yet so I don't know exactly, but I think Drush commands are Symfony CLI commands now so that would probably be the best place to search

Comment: The easiest thing to do would be to find a core/contrib command that has the interface you want to reproduce (in this case selecting items from a list), and copying the method they've used

Comment: It would be nice, but there's no DB connection, so it will fail.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, what you've described is perfectly achievable, you just need to do it the right way

Answer (score 1):

This should work. Drush bootstraps Drupal before discovering module commands, so the first step is to make sure your commands are defined in a `drush.services.yml` file as usual.

From there, you should be able to define dynamic options using [hook options](https://github.com/consolidation/annotated-command#option-event-hook). Since Drush bootstraps Drupal prior to discovering module commands, you should find that the Drupal site is always bootstrapped when your hook is called. You can inject the services you need through your `drush.services.yml` file.

**EDIT** When I read through the comments I thought that you said this was working when you were using `hook_drush_command`, so I answered as if you were asking how to convert and do the same thing in Drush 9. I don't remember the internals of the convoluted Drush 8 bootstrap very well, but I'm not sure this is possible in Drush 8.

Comment: It's working if I place my commands under Drupal direcotry as a Drupal module. But I wanted to be a global module, and in that case I need to put into the `~/.drush/` place, where it doesn't work anymore...

Comment: Did you try setting 'bootstrap' => DRUSH_BOOTSTRAP_FULL?  Check other commands for exact syntax.

Comment: Yes, I set, but it only applies to the callback of the command, and not for the `hook_drush_command()` function. I also tried to bootstrap the drupal inside the `hook_drush_command()` if it's fount, but I didn't fount a way to do it.

Comment: Try writing an extension for Drush 9 following the example of https://github.com/drush-ops/example-drush-extension and my answer above. I don't think it's likely that you're going to be able to make this work in Drush 8.

Comment: Drush 9 does not support Drupal 7, so for this for me is useless.

Comment: Ah, sorry, missed that this was for Drupal 7. I advise you against trying to bootstrap in hook_drush_command. That would be potentially damaging to other commands. You should try implementing your extension using the example-drush-extension anyway, though, as that example DOES work in Drush 8. However, only a subset of the annotated command features work, and I think that dynamic option alteration is one thing that remains unimplemented. I'd accept a PR to Drush 8 that added that feature if you wanted to dig in and extend it. The annotation adapter code is hard to work with, though.